# Ignore blank cells with formulas in Drop Down List

Tags: excel

[image]

This is where all my values are. Range O2 to O50 is populated by formulas. Some return a value while some do not return any values.

When I try to create a dropdown list, I use this formula in the Name Manager. `=OFFSET(‘Sheet1’!$O$2,0,0,COUNTA(‘Sheet1’!$O:$O),1)`

But this formula will include all the blank cells because they have formulas inside.

I cannot erase these formulas even they don’t return any values. Is there a way to ask Excel to ignore blank cells (even they have formulas inside of them) when creating a drop-down list?

Comment: Would your values always be on top or can there be empty cells in-between?

Comment: @JvdV yeah, the values will always be on top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get to this with `COUNTBLANK` (assuming there's a block of values at the top of `$0$2:$0$50` without any blanks interspersed).

```
=OFFSET('Sheet1'!$O$2,0,0,COUNTA('Sheet1'!$O$2:$O$50)-COUNTBLANK('Sheet1'!$O$2:$O$50),1)
```

In action:

[image]

[image]

Comment: so I tried your formula, but if I reference entire column, when I go do Data Validation, an error message will pop up saying "The Source currently evaluates to an error." If I try to define the range (for example $O$2:$O$50, it will only show half of the unique values)...

Comment: What is the revised formula you are using? Make sure you keep the first 'Sheet1'!$O$2 unchanged

Comment: =OFFSET(Names!$O$2,0,0,COUNTA(Names!$O$2:$O$30)-COUNTBLANK(Names!$O$2:$O$30),1). I just changed the sheet's name and the reference range

Comment: And when I click on the formula to see which part is getting selected, the excel will select the entire range (O2:O30)...

Comment: @EmmaG - added a screenshot of the formula and dropdown "in action"

Comment: I finally figured out where I did wrong. So, in my formulas (the formula I used to populate the reference data: CE, CI, etc.), I used IF function, then in the value if false part, I wrote " ", so that's basically writing a blank space into my cells. (In other words, my cells may appeared blank, but they actually contained a blank space in them. In order for the formula you told me to work, I had to change " " to "".

Comment: Ahhhhh yess that would do it.